# DateTime Conversion in GWT. Show IST instead of UTC+5.30 Dynamically

Tags: gwt, timezone, simpledateformat, datetime-format

I have a problem with date to format date in this format "**Wednesday, 13, Aug 2014. 03.41 PM IST**".
I have Tried below code to display date in required format and display with timezone.

**Client Side I have Used**:

```
final DateTimeFormat dtf = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("EEEE, dd, MMM yyyy. hh.mm a z");
System.out.println(dtf.format(new Date()));
```

Client OutPut :- "Wednesday, 13, Aug 2014. 03.37 PM **UTC+5:30**"

**Server Side I have Used**:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd, MMM yyyy. hh.mm a z");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date ));
```

Server Side OutPut is : "Wednesday, 13, Aug 2014. 03.37 PM **IST**"

I need server side output(**Wednesday, 13, Aug 2014. 03.41 PM IST**) will be same on both side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `dtf.format(new Date(), timeZone);` method and pass the required [GWT TimeZone object](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/TimeZone.html) to it.

UPDATE:

Note that you should not create a TimeZone object using an offset method. First, it's not a good idea in general, because it does not take daylight saving time transitions into account. Therefore, you can be off by an hour depending on a date. Second, it won't give you your desired time zone (IST).

You need to use `createTimeZone(java.lang.String tzJSON)` method to create the time zone that you need from [TimeZoneConstants](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/constants/TimeZoneConstants.html).

Comment: Andrei, I have created TimeZone at client side using clientTimeZoneOffset and passed with dtf.format(date, timeZone) But It is not working. It display UTC+5.30

Comment: You need to use `createTimeZone(java.lang.String tzJSON)` method if you want IST time zone. Look at this blog post: http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2012/08/06/the-problem-with-gwts-datetimeformat/

Comment: Hello Andrei, I understand your point but My point is:
If my war is running under UTC+5.30 then show IST
If It is running under UTC+2.00 then show CAT
So, If you know related to this then plz put some code so that I can understand properly.

Comment: @SamirSavasani - Time zone abbreviations are not unique. There are lots of zones that use +2, and there are three different ISTs.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone_abbreviations